# What do decoupled and irrevocable mean in Chisel?

Tags: chisel

I frequently see these terms to modify i/o ports within i/o bundles, as in [here](https://www.chisel-lang.org/chisel3/docs/explanations/bundles-and-vecs.html), but it's unclear what they mean as though this source doesn't directly define them. The chisel-lang docs (as in [here](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/3.3.2/chisel3/util/Decoupled$.html)) reuse the terms in the definition and aren't too helpful.

Comment: Are you asking what do the terms mean? The title is confusing. (besides make sure that you include the question in the body too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both "decoupled" and "irrevocable" are implementations of a ready/valid interface. In both, a consumer asserts a ready to indicate that it can accept data. A producer asserts a valid to indicate that it has data. When both ready and valid are asserted, it is assumed that the consumer grabbed the data---a *transaction* takes place.

The difference between decoupled and irrevocable is that in a decoupled interface, a producer may deassert valid before a transaction takes place. Alternatively, in an irrevocable interface, the producer *will not* deassert valid before a transaction takes place.

There's some documentation to this effect on the [`DecoupledIO`](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/latest/chisel3/util/DecoupledIO.html) and [`IrrevocableIO`](https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/latest/chisel3/util/IrrevocableIO.html) classes.

Do note that the irrevocable guarantee is not enforced. This is just a way for a library writer to clearly state the behavior of some producer. (They may do the wrong thing and not enforce the irrevocable guarantee.) There has been discussion amongst Chisel devs about adding a runtime assertion to enforce irrevocable, but this hasn't happened yet.